# How does one create a filter condition based on a configuration object for filtering data-items of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, dynamic, filter

I have a process which dynamically - depending on checkbox state changes - creates kind of a *`config`* object which describes how the condition for filtering an array of data-items should be built.

A filter configuration might look like this one ...

```
const filter = {
  publicationType: ['type-1', 'type-2'],
  termType: ['term-1', 'term-2'],
  reportFormat: ['xml'],
}
```

A simplified list of data items then looks like that ...

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-1', publicationType: 'type-1' },
  { id: 2, reportFormat: 'xml', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-2' },
  { id: 3, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-2' },
]
```

I would like the condition to match **every category/type** (a configuration's key), but its **value can be either one** from a category's/type's array.

From the provided example data and specifications the expected filter result would be ...

```
[{ id: 2, reportFormat: 'xml', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-2' }]
```

How does an approach look like which builds a correct filter condition based on the provided `filter` configuration object.

Below is my attempt to make a filter function but filtering works properly only on single Select component, if I try to filter on multiple Select components  - data duplicates.

```
const handleFilter = (val) => {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(val);
    const filteredStats = [];

    // loop objects in fetched arr
    for (const item of stat) {
      // loop properties by which filtering data

      filterKeys.forEach((keys) => {
        // check if data property match with a filtering property in array

        const isPresent = val[keys].some((key) => {
          const statProperty = item[keys];
          const filterProperty = key;
          return filterProperty === statProperty;
        });
        if (isPresent) {
          filteredStats.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
    setfilteredState(filteredStats);
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-vqex7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Specify *"by all properties together"* ... does it mean one big `AND` chained condition like `publicationType === 'type-1' && publicationType === 'type-2' && termType === 'term-1' && termType === 'term-2' ... ` ?.. because that won't work or is it more EVERY category/type matching EITHER of its value(s)?

Comment: Where does `reportFormat: 'txt'` come from?

Comment: I add my code and sandbox for example @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approache's base techniques is taking advantage of the fact that almost every `Array` method allows for an additionally passed `target` object which the solution utilizes with e.g. [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Parameters) and  [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Parameters)

The main approach is **reading and applying the filter configuration for every iteration** of the data array's `filter` method.

This function needs to iterate `every` **key-value**(List) pair of a configuration's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for checking whether a specific data-item matches a specifically configured condition-entry.

The latter task is done by another function which can access the data-item and does *"know"* both, this data-item's currently to be checked for **property-key** and the list of possibly valid **property-values**, which makes it easy to check for whether [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the final condition(s) do(es) apply.

There is still an edge case, empty value lists, which need to be handled by the latter function. Since the truthiness of its checking relies on `some` ... (and `some`'s default return value for empty arrays is `false` ... `[].some(x => true) === false`) ... one has to handle this scenario separately by explicitly returning `true` for its fulfilled precondition of `valueList.length === 0`.

```js
function doesBoundItemMatchConditionEntry([key, valueList]) {
  const item = this;
  const itemValue = item[key];
  return ((
    valueList.length === 0
  ) || (
    item.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
    valueList.some(value => value === itemValue)
  ));
}
function doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig(item) {
  // const config = this;
  return Object
    .entries(this)
    .every(doesBoundItemMatchConditionEntry, item);
}

const filterConfig = {
  publicationType: ['type-1', 'type-2'],
  termType: ['term-1', 'term-2'],
  reportFormat: ['xml'],
}
const sampleData = [
  { id: 1, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-1', publicationType: 'type-1' },
  { id: 2, reportFormat: 'xml', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-2' },
  { id: 3, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-2' },
  { id: 4, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-2', publicationType: 'type-1' },
  { id: 5, reportFormat: 'xml', termType: 'term-1', publicationType: 'type-2' },
  { id: 6, reportFormat: 'txt', termType: 'term-1', publicationType: 'type-2' },
]

console.log(
  'sampleData.filter(doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig, filterConfig) ...',
  sampleData.filter(doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig, filterConfig)
);
console.log(
`sampleData.filter(doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig, {
    publicationType: ['type-2'],
    termType: ['term-1'],
    reportFormat: [],
}) ...`,
  sampleData.filter(doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig, {
    publicationType: ['type-2'],
    termType: ['term-1'],
    reportFormat: [],
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey, I added your solution to my code but filter return an empty array

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-vqex7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @frontMaster ... since I voluntarily was keeping this thread alive and also had fun carrying you until here, I would like to continue solving the base problem(s) here. Provide sample data of (a) configuration(s) and some more relevant items to the data list and point to where the code does fail. I neither have a codesandbox account nor do I want to sign in. BTW you need to provide both functions directly into the App module's scope; `handleFilter` then easily is rewritten to `const handleFilter = (config) => { setfilteredState(stat.filter(doesItemMatchConditionsOfBoundConfig, config)); };`.

Comment: @frontMaster ... in addition I would like to know whether I got a correct understanding of how the combined filter condition was intended to work.

Comment: I did't explain correctly, I wanted to make a filter with checkboxes to work together and independent. You solution is working properly when  all filter properties contain data . But if one of the filters properties is empty it doesn't work. Now I need to figure out to make it working. @PeterSeliger

Comment: `const filterConfig = {
  publicationType: ['type-1', 'type-2'],
  termType: ['term-1', 'term-2'],
  reportFormat: [],
}`

For example if reportFormat property empty filter will return an empty array

Comment: One has to specify how empty value lists should be handled. The most easy thing was, to not make configured conditions with empty arrays part of the overall condition. Is this how you would your filter app expect to work?

Comment: Yes, better to make configure object more dynamically and have properties only when it contains some data

Comment: @frontMaster ... done ... works like a charm. I checked it at your shared  codesandbox project as well. Looks like we found the final solution.

Comment: Indeed, appreciate for your time. Your code works perfectly.